# Add REST api to Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, rest, vaadin

I am using Spring boot with Vaadin and I want to open url's for mobile users so, they will login to my system and they will sent data (JSON probably) and fetch data from the system.

Here is my main UI:

```
@SpringUI
public final class mainUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        // Some code to show to the user
    }



    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*",  asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = mainUI .class, productionMode = true)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

}
```

How and where can I add code such that the mobile user can reach my system?

As far as I know, I should create a package named "Services", and add Rest APIs in that file. I couldn't manage to do so.

For example, I want a mobile user to reach `localhost:8080/api/login` method. Where to add this functionality? I am a newbie in this area so any detailed information(written or link to another website) will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is strangely formulated. Actually you do not need to add REST endpoint to Vaadin. The REST end point can be added to the same application though, but it will not be part of the Vaadin servlet. Typically you will add own servlet for it and use e.g. JAX-RS to create those end points.